# Bootstrap-slider custom handle

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I really don't understand why I can't manage to replace the original star handle by a picture of my own. 
Let's rely on that [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/D3GJQn/preview) to understand. 
I read the [author's documentation](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) on that matter: example 10

On the previous plunker I did as it's written that:

HTML:

```
<input id="ex10" type="text" data-slider-handle="custom"/>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-handle.custom {
  background: transparent url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-8/128/Accept-icon.png");
}
```

The url background linked to the picture I want to see as handle. (Replacing the default star).

As you can see here: [image: Plunker Picture - Enable to set background handle]

New picture with Alexandr's comment below: 
Doesn't seem to change anything.

[image: Alexandr's comment]

Comment: I dont see your div .slider-handle.custom . You need #ex10 { //css }

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I updated another picture.

Comment: In this example http://embed.plnkr.co/D3GJQn/preview star it's before pseudo element

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. Tell me how you would proceed and I'll try it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :

```
.slider-handle.custom::before {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  content: '\2605';
  color: #726204;
}
```

to this :

```
 .slider-handle.custom::before {
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      content: "url-of-your-picture";
      color: #726204;
    }
```

You may have to do some adjustment to the line-height depending on the size of custom handle you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

So if you instantiated slider then all you need to do is change your CSS

```
.slider-handle.custom {
  background: transparent none;
  /* Add your background image */
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-8/128/Accept-icon.png");
  background-size: contain;
}

/* Or display content like unicode characters or fontawesome icons */
.slider-handle.custom::before {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Comment this because you will not use star */
  /*content: '\2605'; /*unicode star character*/
  color: #726204;*/
}
```

Comment: I did. You can see it in the last screenshot from plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You should override slider-handle.custom::before

```
.slider-handle.custom::before {
      display:none
}
```